# Manipulando strings em Python

Tags: python

Possuo uma lista com `n` strings. Exemplo:

```
lista = ['0004434-48.2010', 'UNIÃO, '(30 dias úteis) 03/07/2017', '13/07/2017', '0008767-77.2013', 'UNIÃO, '(10 dias úteis) 03/07/2017', '13/07/2017']
```

Meu programa percorre essa lista, porém todos os itens são apresentados como strings. Preciso:

1. Detectar dentre eles o que tenha formato de DATA;
2. Tratar essa string (converter para o formato de data);
3. Detectar entre eles o que tenha NÚMEROS;
4. Tratar essa string (converter para o formato números).

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Qual seria o formato de número? Nenhum ali aparentemente é um número.

Comment: Como é string acredito que você consegue fazer gande parte do que deseja com regex e split

Comment: Aqui `'UNIÃO, '(10 dias úteis) 03/07/2017'` parece me que está uma `'` em falta. É melhor confirmar

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda de todos! Meu problema é q a data que vou usar está junto com essa frase "união, (10 dias úteis)", então não consegui usar exatamente a sugestão sugerida, mas contornei tratando com "2017 in string".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
lista = ['0004434-48.2010',
 'UNIÃO',
 '(30 dias úteis) 03/07/2017',
 '13/07/2017',
 '0008767-77.2013',
 '2017',
 '(10 dias úteis) 03/07/2017',
 '13/07/2017']


for s in lista:
  try:
    print('É data: ', datetime.strptime(s, '%d/%m/%Y'))
  except:
    try:
      print ('É numero, convertido para inteiro ',int(s))
    except:
      print('É string:  ', s )
```

> Output:

```
É string:   0004434-48.2010
É string:   UNIÃO
É string:   (30 dias úteis) 03/07/2017
É data:  2017-07-13 00:00:00
É string:   0008767-77.2013
É numero, convertido para inteiro  2017
É string:   (10 dias úteis) 03/07/2017
É data:  2017-07-13 00:00:00
```

### Alternativa:

```
## Versão 2
print ('#########################')

for s1 in lista:
  for s in s1.split():
    try:
      print('É data: ', datetime.strptime(s, '%d/%m/%Y'))
    except:
      try:
        print ('É numero, convertido para inteiro ',int(s))
      except:
        print('É string:  ', s )
```

> Output:

```
#########################
É string:   0004434-48.2010
É string:   UNIÃO
É string:   (30
É string:   dias
É string:   úteis)
É data:  2017-07-03 00:00:00
É data:  2017-07-13 00:00:00
É string:   0008767-77.2013
É numero, convertido para inteiro  2017
É string:   (10
É string:   dias
É string:   úteis)
É data:  2017-07-03 00:00:00
É data:  2017-07-13 00:00:00
```

[Execute o codigo no repl.it.](https://repl.it/JZc0/3)

Answer (score 0):

Lembrando que caracteres entre aspas simples ou duplas formam strings, então se vc escreveu cada item entre aspas simples, cada item será uma string diferente. Caso queira utilizar outro formato (data, por exemplo), use o formato de data e assim vai

Comment: Mas uma string no formato de data continua sendo uma string. O que você quis dizer com isso exatamente? Aliás, tem como [edit] sua resposta e apresentar um exemplo de código desta solução que indicou?

Comment: Ahhhh sim, achei que queria apenas transformar os dados. Vc quer identificar, DENTRE suas strings, o que é data e numero, certo? se for isso, basta criar um if. Daí se a string possui o formato de data, que seria dd/mm/aaaa, basta vc criar a condição :)